# Android app not restart from mainactivity while after open background

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hello our application works perfect but when our users move the app to background, after a while coming back to app its been crashing.

For example i open the app then change three pages then move the app to background. after open from background 30 minutes its crash because its try to load activity when i resumed

Another applications do this from mainactivity, for example: instagram,twitter vs vs.

another applications not to try load resume activity, they are trying to main activity

how can i start my app from mainactivity when user come back to app from background ?

Comment: Can you paste the crash log

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

well, the better way would be to identify the null objects and reassign or repopulate them in the onResume() method so that the user can actually return to what they were doing.
if you can't or it's not an option, then try this code in every activity that you do not want to return to.

```
override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {

    this.finishAffinity()
    
}
```

this code closes the active activity as soon as the app goes into background so when returned, the app is forced to start from the launcher activity.
Although I am not convinced that this is the best approach. there might be something better.